# There is something in my home folder that makes Kubuntu stuck at login. What is it?

Tags: kubuntu

I have a partition with my home folder mounted at /home and so I login and the screen goes black and the login screen reappears. Where can I find a log or error report or something?

Answer (score 0):

logs are located at /var/log

`~/.xsession-errors` would probably have the error though.

Anyway, try doing what is described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/223634/386527)

If that does not work, you can try regenerating the .xauthority file by deleting it and logging in.

`sudo rm ~/.Xauthority`